Problems installing pyqt6-tools
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [62 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\codes\浜戦《鑴氭湰\pubg-bp2\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user\codes\浜戦《鑴氭湰\pubg-bp2\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\codes\浜戦《鑴氭湰\pubg-bp2\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dap60nhj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dap60nhj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dap60nhj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 603, in setup
          self.update(tool)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dm_4npfx\pyqt6_bc4c54722e2645a68f3f6e75d5947085\project.py", line 157, in update
          raise UserException(
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 650, in _rmtree_unsafe
          os.rmdir(path)
      PermissionError: [WinError 32] 鍙︿竴涓\xaa绋嬪簭姝ｅ湪浣跨敤姝ゆ枃浠讹紝杩涚▼鏃犳硶璁块棶銆\x82: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvcfco1ts'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\tempfile.py", line 905, in onexc
          _os.unlink(path)
      PermissionError: [WinError 5] 鎷掔粷璁块棶銆\x82: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvcfco1ts'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\weakref.py", line 666, in _exitfunc
          f()
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\weakref.py", line 590, in __call__
          return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\tempfile.py", line 935, in _cleanup
          cls._rmtree(name, ignore_errors=ignore_errors)
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\tempfile.py", line 930, in _rmtree
          _shutil.rmtree(name, onexc=onexc)
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 820, in rmtree
          return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onexc)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 652, in _rmtree_unsafe
          onexc(os.rmdir, path, err)
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\tempfile.py", line 920, in onexc
          cls._rmtree(path, ignore_errors=ignore_errors,
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\tempfile.py", line 930, in _rmtree
          _shutil.rmtree(name, onexc=onexc)
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 820, in rmtree
          return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onexc)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 652, in _rmtree_unsafe
          onexc(os.rmdir, path, err)
        File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 650, in _rmtree_unsafe
          os.rmdir(path)
      PermissionError: [WinError 32] 鍙︿竴涓\xaa绋嬪簭姝ｅ湪浣跨敤姝ゆ枃浠讹紝杩涚▼鏃犳硶璁块棶銆\x82: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvcfco1ts'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I want to install the pyqt6-tools package on my Windows using pip. I checked the documentation and it wants you to install it in a virtual environment using venv, but it always shows that there is something in my temporary files that occupies it. This content is not fixed and each installation is different. I also tried to install it through the administrator shell, but the result is the same.
If you have encountered similar problems, I would be very grateful if you can provide an answer.
My python version is 3.12.2 ,pip version is 24.0
